# Nginx 1.6.3 to 1.8 upgrade

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, upgrade

I'm on Linux Mint LMDE. I just receive a upgrade of nginx from 1.6.3 to 1.8.0 with aptitude and now, I got blank page on all my websites

Here my configuration :

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php;

        server_name phpmyadmin.loc;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

It's a basic configuration for phpmyadmin...

I got access log when I go to my index.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/May/2015:11:53:51 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"
```

But no error log, and blank page

Anyone could help me ?

Comment: Did you get an answer that fixed this? I am in the same soup. With "yum update", I'm at 1.8.0 but the old setup doesn't work now. All the suggestions in this thread do not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue. It turned out the the problem was caused by SCRIPT_FILENAME fcgi param. When I added it to virtual host config everything started working:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: Or even batter solve the problem once and for all by editing  `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` and adding this line at the top: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Answer (score 4):

replace

`include fastcgi_params;`

with

`include fastcgi.conf;`

and remove fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME ... in nginx.conf

Comment: Doesn't work. This is what I have - URL of the code snippet is: http://pasted.co/dca1e3e4 -- as this comment screws up formatting. 

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_index index.php;

      #include fastcgi_params;
      #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    }