# Nginx upgrade to 1.8 - Now getting 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, upgrade

Today I upgraded my localhost server from nginx 1.6.3 to 1.8.0 and now all my local websites are getting a **502 bad gateway.**

A standard nginx config file is as follows

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4

    server_name  yii2.dive;
    root        /media/Development/www/yii2/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /media/Development/www/yii2/log/access.log combined;
    error_log   /media/Development/www/yii2/log/error.log warn;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is as follows

```
2015/05/12 14:09:21 [error] 9295#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: yii2.dive, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "yii2.dive"
```

The socket at /var/run/php5-fpm.sock exists so there is no problem there.

I found [someone else with a problem on the same upgrade](https://serverfault.com/questions/690265/nginx-1-6-3-to-1-8-upgrade) but their issue is different to mine and not getting any errors.

I tried adding this line to **/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params** but it does not alleviate the problem.

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Alternatively is there a way to downgrade back to 1.6.2 or 1.6.3 and I can deal with this upgrade at a later date. I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install nginx=1.6.2-1+trusty0
```

But got the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-full (< 1.6.2-1+trusty0.1~) but 1.8.0-1+trusty1 is to be installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.6.2-1+trusty0.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.6.2-1+trusty0.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-naxsi (< 1.6.2-1+trusty0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What are the contents of php-fpm error.log?

Comment: There is nothing regarding errors. Only two lines from the last couple of days in /var/log/php5-fpm.log

[12-May-2015 09:48:48] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[13-May-2015 09:11:22] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

Comment: Ultimately it turned out the problem was most likely with php5-fpm... Unfortunately I'm not entirely sure what was the underlying issue but after reinstalling both php5-fpm and nginx I was able to access my sites locally.

Comment: You need to check the php-fpm error log.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all nginx packets with:

```
aptitude purge nginx nginx-full
```

Than add official nginx deb repos:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ codename nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ codename nginx

wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

Finally install nginx:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx
```

https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

It should work now. If not - see `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

replace

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

with

```
include fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Comment: In which file you had made this changes, kindly give the path of file?

Comment: In your vhost file

Comment: Doesn't work. Same result.